# Executor sequence calls by Project Reactor (or RxJava2)

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java2, project-reactor

I've the following task and I want to resolve it by using Project Reactor (or RxJava)

There are the sources of events. Each event consists of serviceId and some payload. Once as the event is received, we need execute action to specified serviceId with payload. But we should be ensure that the time gap between two requests to the same serviceId must be more or equals than one second. But the requests to the difference services can be performed in parallel.

Also we should note that the count of services is dynamically.

It looks like the following image

[image]

Currently I've have the following code:

```
Flux.create((sink-> eventProvider.listen(new EventListner(){
                public void event(req) {
                    sink.next(req);
                }
            })))
        /* need some logic here */
        .flatMap(req -> requestExecutor.execute(req))
        .doOnNext(res -> responseProcessor.process(res))
        .subscribe();
```

Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the events identify the service that they initiate calls on, you could use the `groupBy()` operator to separate the streams by service. To introduce a delay after each service request, use `flatMap()` with a parameter to single-thread the usage.

In RxJava:

```
observable
  .groupBy(event -> getServiceId( event )) // 1
  .flatMap(serviceObservable -> // 2
       serviceObservable // 3
         .flatMap( ev -> service(serviceObservable.getKey(), ev), 1) // 4
                           .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) // 5
  .subscribe();
```

1. Group the events by the service that they will use. The ID will server as a key later on. This will emit new items when a new service ID is encountered.
2. `serviceObservable` is a `GroupByObservable` that will be processed below.
3. Each emission from this observable is an event that is supposed to go to a single service.
4. `serviceObservable.getKey()` returns the ID of the service to use. I invented a method `service()` which sends an event to a service by the ID of the service. Also, the parameter `1` tells `flatMap()` to single-thread the operation, so only one service request at a time can occur.
5. The `delay()` (or whichever operator you desire) will wait for a second before freeing up the operation.

(Disclaimer: this code is untested, but I have done similar kinds of scheduling in past projects, so the basic idea is sound.)

Answer (score 0):

[Flux.groupBy()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-) will help you in this case.
The operator uses a mapper function to create keys and groups together emitted elements based on the key. You can consider serviceId as a key.

```
Flux.create((sink-> eventProvider.listen(new EventListner(){
            public void event(req) {
                sink.next(req);
            }
        })))
    .groupBy(req -> req.getServiceId()) //group req by serviceId
    .flatMap(reqGroup-> reqGroup..delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) //add minimum delay to the group
    .flatMap(req -> requestExecutor.execute(req))
    .doOnNext(res -> responseProcessor.process(res))
    .subscribe();
```

You can also add different delays based on the serviceId. Check below snippet as example - even integers will be delayed by 2 sec seconds and odd by 1 second.

```
    Flux.range(1, 20)
    .groupBy(integer -> integer % 2)
    .flatMap(integerGroupedFlux -> {
      Flux<Integer> integerFlux;
      if (integerGroupedFlux.key() == 0) { //even integers
        integerFlux = integerGroupedFlux.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
      } else {
        integerFlux = integerGroupedFlux.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
      }
      return integerFlux;
    })
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```